# Excel VBA - Workbook("") setting workbook name as a variable input from userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to set the Workbook name as a variable, which is specified by a user in the userform, txtWBName

eg,

```
sWBName = userform1.txtWBName

Set wb = Workbooks(" + sWBName + "): wb.Activate
```

I not quite sure how to code it, between the ""...

Can someone please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the variable name like

```
Workbooks(sWBName)
```